# For statement returns unexpected value on last assignment

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a simple "cipher" to assign the letters in a string the value of a reversed alphabet (e.g. a=z b=y, etc..) I built a for statement that seems to work until the last call and instead of giving the reversed value instead gives the original value.

I commented out each line in the for statement and then worked through them one at a time to check their returns. The second to last statement (c = rev.indexOf(c);) give the value of 25, 24, 23 (as expected) so I don't understand why when it looks them up in the "letters" matrix it gives a return of a, b, c instead of z, y, x.

```
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'y', 'x', 'z'];
var rev = letters.reverse();

var stringy = function(n){
    ns = n.split("");
    for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
            c = ns[i];
            c = rev.indexOf(c);
            c = letters[c];
            console.log(c);
    }
}

stringy("abc");
```

Comment: @chchrist What does this have to do with closures, or for loops for that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`letters.reverse()` doesn't just return the reversed array. It reverses the array in place.

If you check the contents of `letters` after `letters.reverse()` you'll see that the order has been reversed.

You can use `.slice()` to make a copy of the array, which you can then reverse:

```
var rev = letters.slice().reverse();
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't realize that .reverse behaved this way.

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone, `sort` does as well, I'm not fond of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to [zzzzBov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39233476/3231537) information to the `Array.reverse()` method, I thought I would add an answer that doesn't require reversing your letters. There is no need to keep 2 variables just to reverse them based on the index, just find the index in the `letters` array and search from the end of the `letters` array back.

I added a slightly modified version of your code, to show how you could make it yourself a bit easier and added some code comments where I thought appropriate

```js
// make your debugging easier
'use strict';

var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'y', 'x', 'z'];

var getReversedCypher = function( text, sequence, unmatched ) {
  if (!text) {
    return '';
  }
  var ns = text.split(''),
      cypher = [], 
      lastLetterIndex = sequence.length - 1;
  
  // use strict adds forEach on arrays
  ns.forEach(function(char) {
    var index = sequence.indexOf(char);
    if (index < 0) {
      // couldn't find a match, you could throw an error, I chose to add an extra character
      cypher.push( unmatched || '-' );
    } else {
      // no need to use a reversed lookup, just search the table from the end
      cypher.push( sequence[lastLetterIndex-index] );
    }
  });
  return cypher.join('');
};

// make some utility methods to still use your simple function
var encode = function( text ) {
  return getReversedCypher( text, letters, '-' );
};

var decode = function( text ) {
  return getReversedCypher( text, [].concat(letters).reverse(), ' ' );
};
    
var encoded = encode("this is the sound of speech"), decoded = decode(encoded);

console.log('cypher: ' + encoded);
console.log('decoded: ' + decoded);
```

Comment: It's like you were reading my mind :) This is what I was working on next. Thank you very much for this answer, I can learn a lot from working through this.